# Why split function ignores '\n' even if I don't specify the delimiter?

Tags: python, python-2.7

According to python documentation.

> str.split([sep[, maxsplit]])

If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a None separator returns [].

But,

```
str = 'L1 \nL2 \nL3'
print str.split()
```

returns `['L1','L2','L3']`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whitespace consists of the characters `' '`, `'\t'`, `'\r'`, and `'\n'`. Therefore, `" \n"` is a single run of consecutive whitespace.